# Datagridview not showing correct rowcount

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I made a gridview where items are added and a function is called to calculate the amount

after adding a item to list i call

```
Private Sub totalimsum()
    Dim totalsum As Double = 0
    Dim totalitem As Double = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvitemlist.Rows.Count - 1
        totalsum += dgvitemlist.Rows(i).Cells("Total").Value
        'totalitem += dgvitemlist.Rows(i).Cells("qty").Value
    Next
    Label16.Text = dgvitemlist.Rows.Count.ToString()
    amttotal = totalsum.ToString()
    txttotal.Text = amttotal
    calctotal()
End Sub
```

it works perfect
but when a row is deleted i again call the function to recalculate the amount but it miscalculate the amount and i found that rowcount is 1 more than row present in the datagridview so i added a new function and calling it but i think it is not a solution

```
    Private Sub totalimsumd()
    Dim totalsum As Double = 0
    Dim totalitem As Double = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To dgvitemlist.Rows.Count - 2
        totalsum += dgvitemlist.Rows(i).Cells("Total").Value
        'totalitem += dgvitemlist.Rows(i).Cells("qty").Value
    Next
    Label16.Text = dgvitemlist.Rows.Count.ToString()
    amttotal = totalsum.ToString()
    txttotal.Text = amttotal
    calctotal()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding the data source of the `DataGridView` which means you reload the contents of the `DataGridView`.

Or

You may try to use the `dgv.update()`; and `dgv.refresh()`; methods whenever you delete a row.

Comment: tried 
dgv.update(); 
dgv.refresh();
but not working 
it still shows count more than actual count

Comment: One thing to remember is that an "empty" datagridview has 1 record only if the AllowUsersToAddRow property is set to true. Otherwise, the row count will be 0.

Comment: allowusertoaddrow is set to false .

Comment: You did not show us your code, on how you add data to dgv. if you use bindingsource, and when you delete a row, is detelete from database too, then a dgv.refresh() AND a BindingSource.ResetBindings(False) is enough !